# Oncreateoptions menu not called

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, oncreateoptionsmenu

Hi i have a strange scenario where onCreateOptionsmenu not getting called when i run the program but when i keep a breakpoint it gets called for a device < 3 (Android OS) FOr Android OS > 3 fones its getting called . below is my code

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        android.util.Log.e("mmmmmmmmmmmmm", "Coming insside oncreateoptions menu");
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (FoneclayUtility.m_bIsLoggedIn == true)
        {
            android.util.Log.e("mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm", "Setting logout menu");
            getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_logout, menu);
        }
        else
        {
            getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Your code compiles? Where is the return statement for the boolean?

Comment: you have to return true !!

Comment: sorrry copy paste error ..i have edited